# Is it possible to exclude tests on firefox , safari and Edge in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I am looking to test a scenario where the application blocks the user to proceed edge browser and displays a message that the application is unsupported on edge.

I am unsure if we can exclude test suite on various browsers and make it run only on chrome ?

Comment: Isn't that what capabilities is used for? If you don't want them to run on Edge just don't put it in the config as an option. Or is it that you have some tests that can run on Edge and some that cannot?

Comment: yes i want only some tests to run on Edge

Answer (score 0):

You can tell protractor which tests should run on each browser by adding a `specs` property to each browser in the `multiCapabilities` section. If `multiCapabilities` is specified then the `capabilities` property will be ignored.

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  specs: ['spec/chromeOnlySpec.js', 'spec/chromeOnlySpec2.js']
}, {
  browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
  specs: ['spec/runsOnEdgeSpec.js', 'spec/runsOnEdge2Spec.js']
}]
```